# Binomial Inequality in which Binomial coefficient is in square root.

Tags: inequality

> $$1\cdot \sqrt{C_{1}}+2\cdot \sqrt{C_{2}}+\cdots \cdots +100\cdot \sqrt{C_{100}}\leq \frac{1}{2}\cdot (2^{100}-1)+\frac{20301}{12}$$
>
> where $\displaystyle C_{r}=\binom{n}{r}$

Try: Using Cauchy Schwarz Inequaity

$$\bigg(1^2+2^2+\cdots \cdots +100^2\bigg)\bigg(C_{1}+C_{2}+\cdots \cdots +C_{100}\bigg)\geq \bigg(1\cdot \sqrt{C_{1}}+2\cdot \sqrt{C_{2}}+\cdots \cdots +100\cdot \sqrt{C_{100}}\bigg)^2$$

$$\bigg(1\cdot \sqrt{C_{1}}+2\cdot \sqrt{C_{2}}+\cdots \cdots +100\cdot \sqrt{C_{100}}\bigg)\leq \bigg[\frac{100\cdot 101\cdot 201}{6}\cdot (2^{100}-1)\bigg]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

i am not understand how can i prove my original inequality,

could some help me , Thanks

Comment: What does $C_n$ mean?

Comment: I think, $C_n=\binom{100}{n}$.

Comment: I think you meant $(C_1+\cdots+C_{100})$ in your application of Cauchy Schwartz.

Comment: The inequality seemed to be very loose. Try comparing terms of the form $r\sqrt{C_r}$, we can estimate that the maximal one happens at $r_m = 51$ or $52$. So the left hand side is less than $100\times r_m\sqrt{C_{r_m}}$. But $\sqrt{C_{r_m}} < 2^{50}$, so the entire stuff is less than $5200\times 2^{50}$.

Comment: Thanjs Hw Chu i did not understand , please explain me in detail.

Comment: I think your attempt gave similar results. The right hand side of your last equation is simply much less than $2^{99}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$
2\bigg[\frac{100\cdot 101\cdot 201}{6}\cdot (2^{100}-1)\bigg]^{\frac{1}{2}}\le \frac{100\cdot 101\cdot 201}{6} + (2^{100}-1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

By C-S,
as you have done,

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}\right)^2
&\le \sum_{k=1}^n k^2\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}(2^n-1)\\
&\lt\dfrac{2(n+1)^3}{6}2^n\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{3}2^n\\
\text{so}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k\sqrt{\binom{n}{k}}
&\lt\dfrac{(n+1)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{3}}2^{n/2}\\
\end{array}
$

and this is less than
$2^{n-1}$
for $n \ge 12$
according to Wolfy.

So it is much less
for your case of
$n = 100$.